# outline-mode にてある heading が sibling の中で末の要素であることを確認するには？

Tags: elisp

outline-mode にてある heading が sibling の中で末の要素であることを確認したいと考えています。

イメージとしては、
(defun last-sibling-heading-p ()
   ......)

が定義されるイメージなのですが、これはどう実装したらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「outline-mode にてある heading が sibling の中で末の要素であることを確認したい」
ということだと、

1. outline-modeのフォーマットのテキストデータをパーズして、その中の「末の要素」だけ抜き出す
2. Emacsのoutline-mode 中でをカーソルが、ある heading 上にあって、sibling の中では「末の要素」になっているかを確認する関数を作りたい

等の解釈ができるかと思います。

自分は、2の場合で回答したいと思います。
とりあえず、動作としては、

```
(defun last-sibling-heading-p ()
  (save-excursion
    (let ((start (point))
          prev)
      (ignore-errors (outline-forward-same-level 1))
      (setq prev (point))
      (ignore-errors (outline-forward-same-level 1))
      (and (= prev (point))
           (>= start (point))))))

;; M-x fooでカーソル位置のsiblingが「末の要素」かを確認する
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (message (if (last-sibling-heading-p) "last" "butlast")))
```

のようなものを想定されているのでしょうか。
このコマンドの場合

```
* A
** a
** b
** c
* B
* C
```

のような場合、cの位置にカーソルがあれば、"last"と表示されます。
もしこの動作が希望ということであれば、上の実装はいい加減なものですので、
emacs-lispに詳しい方がもっと良い実装を教えてくれるかもしれません。